# HTML, Incrementing input value with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to increase the value entered in the amount input by 10% in real time and show it in the amount + commission input, how can I do it? I will be glad if you help me thank you

[image: inputs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, read the input value on change and then calculate the final amount after commission and display it in the second input field which will be disabled.

```js
$('input').on( "input", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).val() );
  let val = parseInt($(this).val());
  let comm = 10;
  let total = val + val*comm/100;
  $('input[name="total"]').val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="amount"/>
<input type="text" name="total" disabled />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the code you have so we can help you.

However, you can make this with Jquery using `.change()` method

```
let amount = 0;
let amountPlusCommission = 0;

const commission = 0.1;

$("#yourinputID").change(function () {
    const value = $(this).val();
    amount = value;
    amountPlusCommission = value + (value * commission);
    $("#yourSecondinputID").val(amountPlusCommission);
});
```

Change the yourinputID with the first input ID and yourSecondinputID with the result input ID.

### EXTRA: `.keyup()` function is much better for this

```
$("#yourinputID").keyup(function () {...})
```

`.change()` detects when the input changes, but `.keyup()` detects when the user releases a key on the input and is much more efficient.